# How to avoid reinstantiating regex multiple times?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have written a solution for advent of code 2023, day 1 in Rust and got it to work. The general structure is like this:

```
fn parse_number(line: &str) -> Option<i32> {
  Regex::new(...).unwrap()...
}

fn parse_line(line: &str) -> (i32, i32) {
  let first_parsed = parse_number(&line).unwrap();
  let last_parsed = parse_number(&line).unwrap_or(first_parsed);
  (first_parsed, last_parsed)
}

fn day_1(path: &str) -> i32 {
  let file = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("ok");
  file
    .lines()
    .fold(0, |acc, line| {
      ...parse_line(...)...
    })
}
```

Now what I see as a possible performance optimization would be avoiding to reinitialize the same regexes over and over again, so I want to do something like this:

```
fn parse_number(re: Regex, line: &str) -> Option<i32> {
  re...
}

fn parse_line(first_regex: Regex, second_regex: Regex, line: &str) -> (i32, i32) {
  let first_parsed = parse_number(first_regex, &line).unwrap();
  let last_parsed = parse_number(second_regex, &line).unwrap_or(first_parsed);
  (first_parsed, last_parsed)
}

fn day_1(path: &str) -> i32 {
  let first_regex = Regex::new(...).unwrap();
  let second_regex = Regex::new(...).unwrap();
  let file = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("ok");
  file
    .lines()
    .fold(0, |acc, line| {
      ...parse_line(&first_regex, &second_regex, &line)...
    })
}
```

The issue is that the borrow checker complains that I am moving the regex objects (which I obviously am), but what are the common patterns to handle this? I would prefer being able to reuse the first two regex objects for all operations, but a second priority would be cloning them, which I assume is still faster than what I do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods on `Regex` take a reference to self as receiver (`&self`, not `self`), so you can just swap the owned value for a reference to it instead:

```rust
use regex::Regex;
fn parse_number(re: &Regex, line: &str) -> Option<i32> {
    todo!()
}
```

It's generally a good idea to take a reference instead of something owned when you can get away with it.

Since the regular expressions are more a property of the `parse_line` function I'd instead use a lazily initialized `static` there instead like tadman and Masklinn suggest:

```rust
use std::sync::OnceLock;
fn parse_line(line: &str) -> (i32, i32) {
    static RE: OnceLock<(Regex, Regex)> = OnceLock::new();
    let (first_regex, last_regex) = RE.get_or_init(|| (Regex::new("").unwrap(), Regex::new("").unwrap()));

    let first_parsed = parse_number(first_regex, &line).unwrap();
    let last_parsed = parse_number(last_regex, &line).unwrap_or(first_parsed);
    (first_parsed, last_parsed)
}
```

Comment: I'm also a big fan of `lazy_static!` so these are instantiated only once per execution.

Comment: In modern Rust you'd usually use a [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) since it's the stdlib. And eventually [`LazyLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.LazyLock.html) should stabilise.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the `regex!` macro from the `once_cell` crate [here](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/index.html#lazily-compiled-regex), and optionally replace `once_cell::sync::OnceCell` with `std::sync::OnceLock`. Here is a MVE:

```rust
macro_rules! regex {
    ($re:literal $(,)?) => {{
        static RE: std::sync::OnceLock<regex::Regex> = std::sync::OnceLock::new();
        RE.get_or_init(|| regex::Regex::new($re).unwrap())
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let re = regex!(r"^\d*$");
    let matches = ["", "a", "b2", "3"]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|s| re.is_match(s))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{matches:?}");  // [true, false, false, true]
}
```